# Unable to run fastri on cygwin: uninitialized constant Gem::Version (NameError)

Tags: emacs, rubygems, cygwin, ri

I'm trying to setup fastri (http://eigenclass.org/hiki/fastri) on emacs running on cygwin in windows. The ruby install is also from cygwin, not the windows version of ruby. 
After downloading, unpacking the tarball and running setup.rb, when I attempt to run qri or fri, I get the following error message:

```
    [/cygdrive/g]$qri
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/ri/ri_paths.rb:63: uninitialized constant Gem::Version (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/ri/ri_paths.rb:59:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/ri/ri_paths.rb:59
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/fastri/util.rb:38:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/fastri/util.rb:38
    from /usr/bin/qri:6:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/qri:6
```

My ruby version and gem environment:

```
[/cygdrive/g]$ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i386-cygwin]
[/cygdrive/g]$gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i386-cygwin]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-cygwin
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/rrajagop/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

I took a look at ri_paths.rb to figure out how Gem::Version should be included in the file, but I couldn't figure it out. I tried adding both `require 'gem/version'` and `require 'version'` in ri_paths.rb, but no joy. I get  `'require': no such file to load -- version (LoadError)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it working. 
Adding `require 'rubygems/version'` in ri_path.rb fixed it.

Basically, used `puts $:` to figure out the paths that require will search thru', found out where `Gem::Version` was defined (I already had a pre-built tags table for ruby and all my gems, so this was easy), and worked out the path to version from the closest component of the search path. Sounds simple, right? Of course, all this took me a couple of days, the ruby noob that I am.